# Getting a centered DIV to move down the page after a short delay

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $('#container').fadeIn('800');
   $('#container').css({margin: '(0px auto 0px auto)'});
   $('#container').animate({margin: '(60px auto 0px auto)'}, 20000).delay(100);
});
```

I have the container to fade in but I'd like it to slide down 60px from the top margin after a delay. I can't get this to work for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain your effects

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $('#container').css({margin: '(0px auto 0px auto)'})
     .fadeIn(800)
     .delay(100)
     .animate({margin: '(60px auto 0px auto)'}, 20000);
});
```

Comment: That is far more elegant than my answer.  Thank you for showing me a better way.

Comment: This did not actually move the DIV down the page using the new margin. Am I going about it wrong using margins?

Comment: try a `.animate({marginTop:60},20000)` since you're only changing the top margin

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Is there a way to animate the fade in at the same time as it moving down?

Comment: `.css({margin: '(0px auto 0px auto)', opacity:0}).show()
     .animate({margin: '(60px auto 0px auto)', opacity:1}, 20000)`  .fadeIn sets opacity to zero shows then animates opacity to 1, you simply include the same in your css start and animate end.

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn doesn't block while it executes, so the other two lines executed as soon as the fadeIn was called, not completed.  fadeIn takes a callback parameter.  Put your other 2 lines in an anonymous function as the callback.

I haven't tried it but I believe this should work.

```
$(window).bind("load", function() {
   $('#container').fadeIn('800', function() {
     $('#container').css({margin: '(0px auto 0px auto)'});
     $('#container').animate({margin: '(60px auto 0px auto)'}, 20000).delay(100);
   });
});
```